# Swift returning unwrapped Element in a generic function that takes in optional Element?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

The idea here is to take in an optional element and return either an empty array or an array with a non-optional element embedded. Wrote up a quick generic solution and I am getting an error `Using '!' is not allowed here; perhaps '?' was intended?`.

Is there a way to unwrap Element and use it in return value?

```
public func arrayWithOptional(optional: Element?) -> [Element!] {
    if let optional = optional {
        return [optional]
    }
    return []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function generic:

```
public func arrayWithOptional<Element>(optional: Element?) -> [Element] {
    if let optional = optional {
        return [optional]
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I wasn't adding the `<Element>` specifier!

Comment: Actually, the error was because you had [Element!] as the return type instead of [Element].  That is where the ! is not allowed - the elements of the array must either optional (Element?) or not optional (Element).  Implicitly unwrapped optionals (Element!) have not been allowed in arrays since Swift 4.2 (I think).

Comment: @guywithmazda True, but I think OP meant to have a *generic* function - that's why I added `<Element>` as well.